# How to include an icon above some text on MDL button

Tags: material-design-lite

How do you include an icon above some text in a material design lite button component?  There are not any examples in the documentation.  My attempt does not work.

```
   <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td><i class="material-icons">add</i></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Text</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not follow the MDL guidelines to the mark but this might get the job done for you.  See example [codepen](http://codepen.io/kriddy800/pen/MeKYPM)

```
<button class="my-btn mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
        <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
        <label> text</label>
</button>


.my-btn {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:auto !important;

  >*{
    align-self:center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to modify your above CSS to make the icon centered on the left side instead of on top?  I have tried, but can't get it to work in FireFox.

Comment: Just remove the align-self:center from the icon

Comment: I tried that on your codepen and it does not work.  The icon is too high.

Comment: Ah my mistake you mean left of the text.  I've forked the [codepen](http://codepen.io/kriddy800/pen/MebRME) let me know if this is what you are looking for